# How to use "require" in javascript, with qliksense?

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I am attempting to pull the current filters from my qlik sense server. I pulled some code from their [API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/SelectionAPI/qlik-selectionState-interface.htm?_ga=2.218972383.734518631.1594147823-1318608589.1593781993), but it's giving me issues. here is the code:

```js
require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
  var app = qlik.openApp("(my app id)", config);
  //do stuff
});
```

I'm getting `VM2352:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openApp' of undefined`
I am fairly unfamiliar with javascript, and I tried to look into how `require` works. Unfortunately everywhere else it seems to have only one argument, whereas the code above has two. Does anybody know what's up?

Edit:

I now realize that the import sets qlik in the function argument as the module "js/qlik". However, the code still doesn't work regardless. If I do `console.log(qlik)` inside the function, it says "undefined". If I log the return from the require, it's the code of the original module.

Comment: where are you trying to run this? in the dev-hub or outside qlik (like localhost or hosted somewhere else)

Comment: Janky as it may be, I'm running it from console in the webpage. The end goal is to take the selections out of the iframe that qlik sense is in, and put them on another spot on the page. For now, I'm trying to test things before I commit to writing a js file for it.